# Grouping reputation by question when post removed

Tags: feature-request

The following is my day's reputation changes so far on Stack Overflow:

```
+10   7 hours ago    upvote     My php script shows results as deleted, yet phpmyadmin shows results still  
 +2   1 min ago      edit       Any best link to learn login system using php mysql  
 +2   1 hour ago     edit       Advice needed on best time to edit/delete exams  
 -1   5 mins ago     downvoted  Any best link to learn login system using php mysql  
 -1  15 mins ago     removed    Advice needed on best time to edit/delete exams  
 -1   1 hour ago     downvoted  Advice needed on best time to edit/delete exams
```

My initial reaction was "This can't be! Why did the removal of the question penalize me when I had already lost one reputation point from downvoting an answer? Was there some sort of mistake?" It wasn't until I looked a few times before I noticed that the -1 from the removal of the question was because I had successfully edited the question earlier, therefore evening out the reputation from the question at 0.

I tried to find something on the reputation page to allow grouping of reputation by question instead of by time, but I couldn't. As Daniel Fischer found, while voting does get grouped together when sorting [by post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/899126/glaciesofpacis?tab=reputation&sort=post), votes and the removal of a post are not grouped. Would this be a good feature to add, or is it relatively minor?